# Unable to configure Load Balancer and Target Group?

Tags: kubernetes, amazon-ec2

I am able to configure Nginx for NodePort and access it, but when I configure Load Balancer and Target Group for Nginx I am not able to access. I think I am doing something wrong and I cannot troubleshoot it as I am quite new to Kubernetes.

**nginx-service.yaml**

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: nginx-service
  labels:
    app: nginx
    svc: test-nginx
spec:
  type: LoadBalancer
  selector:
    app: nginx
  ports:
    - protocol: TCP
      port: 8080
      targetPort: 80
      nodePort: 30000
```

**Load Balancer and Target group configuration**

[image: lb1]
[image: lb2]
[image: lb3]
[image: lb4]
[image: lb5]
[image: lb6]
[image: lb7]
[image: lb8]
[image: lb9]
[image: lb10]

[image: lb11]

Comment: refer official doc to install the controll and you can use the ALB as the ingress to handle traffic : https://aws.amazon.com/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/eks-alb-ingress-aws-waf/

Comment: Configuration looks OK, check the firewall rules to enable traffic to instances,  might solve the issue

Answer (score 0):

You need to use ingress controller to do the same thing.
That will automatically create the load balancer and target group from the file itself.

You can watch the videos and tutorials for the same.

Answer (score 0):

Your image attachment indicated that your ALB was attached with the VPC default security group. Your EC2 instance security group will need to have inbound rule for the default security group for connectivity. You can automate this process by using the [AWS LB Controller](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/eks/latest/userguide/alb-ingress.html).